# How to improve "MAX" for "GROUP BY" over geo data on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table of addresses for companies with 3 columns: **company_id**, **lat**, **lon**.

I need to have nearest distances to each companies.
I use **cube** and **earthdistance** extensions for PostgreSQL.

Query work fine but slowly:

```
SELECT
 company_id,
 MIN(earth_distance(ll_to_earth(lat,lon), ll_to_earth(53.96,83.96))) AS distance
FROM companies
GROUP BY company_id;
```

GIST index like:

```
CREATE INDEX i_name on companies USING gist(ll_to_earth(lat, lon));
```

not using.

How can i resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using PostGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general an index may help you to find few rows from a large table or increases speed for queries with `ORDER BY`. Your query needs to scan all rows in the table, and it does a complex computation for all the rows. Thus, an index cannot help you, because Postgres doen't use indexes as precomputed values.

You should instead precompute the value for `ll_to_earth(lat, lon)` into a separate column, and use this column in your query.

Comment: Thank you! It does help. My execution time speed up to 3 times.

Comment: One more question. Do you have any ideas how to increase the speed of my query even more?

Comment: I don't know `ll_to_earth()`. Ensure that it has the modifier `IMMUTABLE` or `STATIC`.

Answer (score 0):

## Indexed with PostGIS

You need a KNN index.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

ALTER TABLE companies ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT 4326);
UPDATE companies
  SET geog = ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geogprahy;

SELECT DISTINCT ON (company_id)
  company_id,
  ST_Distance(company_id,ST_Point(83.96,53.96)::geography)
FROM companies
ORDER BY company_id, geog <=> ST_Point(83.96,53.96)::geography DESC;
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mistake on `ST_Distance(company_id, ...` and on `geog <=> ...`?